# Html Browser: best practice to pass user SID to server-side

Tags: .net, security, architecture, legacy

Legacy application (win32 clients + centralized db) has 40+ installations in a company & lacks the ability to be extended by plugins. Legacy authentication system relies on computer name, user name & user SID (there is no single DOMAIN server in a company, there are dozens of workgroups).

I'm going to build stand-alone intranet site that would provide additional functions to legacy ones. I want to use current authentication data - this way I have to pass SID from html browser somehow without prompting user to enter login/password e.t.c.

Does UserSID/WorkstationName/UserName are sendable via HTTP(s) protocol after being configured some way? 
If no what technologies would you suggest to use: 
May be I shall use [Silverlight + WMI abilities](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kirtan007/2572/Default.aspx) or may be it's possible to access WMI from javascript (so I should consider traditional ajax).

Another question: what is the best practice to send UserName,WorkStationName,SID in terms of security. Shall I pass it as function params from client to server, or may be I shall configure this params sendable via communication protocol (if I'm going to use WCF communication and it's configurable this way)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How serious is your work place about security?  Surely if security was taken seriously they'd take the time and $ to set-up a proper domain?  Otherwise you're going to spend eternity looking for work-arounds to issues like this.  Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you, Adrian, I'll have a talk with admins.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set in IE *User Authentication->Logon->Automatic logon with current user name and password* ? In theory that should work: set this option and save user/pwd in stored accounts.

I have used such approach successfully.

Comment: Ok, thank you I'll give it a try in a few days! But I suppose it willn't work for me because I'll have to duplicate all accounts on server (as we have no DOMAIN authentication)